# Simple heap program- what does this variable do

Tags: c++, heap

```
void ReheapDown( int* heap, int top, int swpIndx, int numElements )  {
    int leftChild = 2 * top + 1;
    int rightChild = 2 * top + 2;
    int minChild;
    if (leftChild < numElements) {
        // find subscript of smallest child
        if (rightChild >= swpIndx || heap[leftChild] < heap[rightChild])
            minChild = leftChild;
        else
            minChild = rightChild;
        // if data at top is greater than smallest
        // child then swap and continue
        if (heap[top] > heap[minChild]) {
            swap( heap[top], heap[minChild] );
            ReheapDown( heap, minChild, swpIndx, numElements );
        }
    }
```

This is for a simple heap. ReheapDown is used partly for removing items in the heap. What does `swpIndx` do though? (I need to know to do a homework assignment, where I'm supposed to write the function that removes a certain key in the heap.)

Comment: It's only used once in the function, try to figure out that `if` where its used...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove a key from a heap, we might want to swap it with the last key in the heap before deleting it, otherwise there would be a gaping hole in the heap.

However, swapping the last node with the node we want to remove can upset the ordering of the heap, which is where that **ReheapDown** method that you provided comes in.

I believe the *swpIndex* parameter is the index into which we have placed the element that we wish to remove. So that part of the code basically says:

```
if (there exists a left child) {
    if (there is no right child || left child < right child)
        minChild <- left child
    else
        minChild <- right child
}
```

I think that parameter is unnecessary though, since it seems that it's only purpose is to check for the existence of the left and right child; this can also be accomplished by comparing the leftChild and rightChild indices to numElements.

Hope this helps :)